# Using Liquibase to create snowflake storedprocedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase

I am trying to create stored procedure using liquibase, but while doing liquibase update it is failing with below error:

```
Starting Liquibase at 11:37:58 (version 4.4.0 #11 built at 2021-06-09 16:36+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.4.0
syntax error line 5 at position 5 unexpected '$'. [Failed SQL: (1003) create or replace procedure SP_TEST_AZURE()
    returns string
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var sql_cmd
```

Is there configuration missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that Liquidbase has issue with `$$`. I suspect:

> [The endDelimiter SQL attribute](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/enddelimiter-sql-attribute.html)
>
> Use endDelimiter in SQL for PROCEDURE and FUNCTION
>
> An endDelimiter may be used when the changeset contains SQL to create a stored procedure or function that contains the default ';' end delimiter. To avoid incomplete statements being sent to the database, the changeset must be marked to have a different endDelimiter.
>
> **The endDelimiter must be specified for some dbms systems to run multiple statements.**

Setting it to empty string: `endDelimiter=""` should resolve it.

Comment: yep it had end delimiter defaulted to ';', let me check that option.. Thanks

Comment: Perfect, you are correct, thanks when i made endDelimiter="" it executed successfully